# Pythagorean theorem

Tags: geometry

The Pythagorean theorem is typically written as

$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$

where $a$ and $b$ are the two shorter sides (legs) of a right triangle and $c$ is its longest side (the hypotenuse).

Given the exponent powers $c^{2\, \times\, 1/2} = c$, why cant I express "$a = c - b$".

The correct answer given was $\sqrt{c^2 - b^2}$

Comment: ...what? I mean, what do you mean "given the exponent powers $\frac {c^2}2 = c$", do you just mean $c = 2$?

Comment: $3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2$ (because $9 + 16 = 25$) but $3 + 4 \neq 5$, so $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ does not imply $a + b = c$.

Comment: Using the notation given by you, if we are allowed to have "a = c -  b", then we are also allowed to have "a + b = c", ......then why do we go through all the trouble in stating the theorem as $"a^2 + b^2 = c^2"$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to think more carefully about what is going on.

Note that $$25=9+16 \text { or } 3^2+4^2=5^2$$ but it is not true that $$3=5-4$$ instead it is true that $$3=\sqrt{3^2}=\sqrt {5^2-4^2}$$ Using very simple examples as a check can help you to avoid mistakes, and also to see where the mistake is. But don't rely on them to replace formal arguments - sometimes simple cases miss the point.

Comment: From your example, it is true but I am looking at the exponent distribution rule (cd)^2 = c^2 * d^2

why not (a^2+b^2)^1/2 = a^2*1/2 + b^2*1/2

Comment: @optimus $(a\pm b)^2=a^2\pm 2ab+b^2\neq a^2+b^2$ unless $2ab=0$ ie $a=0$ or $b=0$.

Comment: wow Mark, I got it. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

That is because $\sqrt{c^2-b^2}$ is not in general equal to $c-b$.

If you are raising things to a power, in general you can't do it term by term (just try some explicit examples to see why this is).

In that particular case you can either write $a^2 = c^2-b^2$ or $a = \sqrt{c^2-b^2}$.

Comment: "...is not **in general** equal to..."

Comment: For completeness, if $\sqrt {c^2-b^2}=c-b$ then $c^2-b^2=(c-b)^2$ which gives us $c=b$ or $b=0$

Comment: I'm not sure this answer adds anything to Mark Bennet's answer. That's why I downvoted it.

Comment: @Timothy considering my answer was written before Mark's, 5 years ago, I'm not sure what's your issue...

Comment: @FelipeJacob You could think of it this way. The downvote is not a criticism. Downvoting answers that don't add anything to another better answer is what we do because it ends up helping Stack Exchange. Maybe your answer was useful at the time but it's no longer needed. I'm just suggesting all this. I'm not telling you to do it because I want to be careful not to criticize you. I don't actually know much about the rules and policies of Stack Exchange. I'm just guessing how it should be done.